# How to implement non-blocking PUSH messages in Rabbit.js?

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq, message-queue

My application currently uses RabbitMQ to queue and process messages to initiate data streams and to pass the streamed data to a processing area.

Because we only want one client to consume the data stream and only one client to process the streamed data, I am currently using PUSH messages.

The issue I am finding is that if I acknowledge the PUSH message to initiate the data stream and that process fails, the message will not be requeued. If I do not acknowledge the message, none of my other PUSH messages will be received until after I either acknowledge the data stream message or the process dies.

I have looked at REQUEST/REPLY messages, however I think the same issue may apply here, where I need to requeue automatically should the process/server die.

Is it possible to use non-blocking PUSH messages?

Comment: what is "PUSH messages"?

Comment: @DerickBailey - Rabbit.JS explains it pretty well - http://www.squaremobius.net/rabbit.js/#toc_7

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps of value is the "qos" / prefetch setting for consumers: https://www.rabbitmq.com/consumer-prefetch.html It's possible to set the value to greater than one to allow a single consumer to get more than one message at a time. Would this result in the non-blocking PUSH (read only) message you're looking for?